# Devise for Rails - Validate username as email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I followed [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) guide to use Username and Email in devise authentication, but when I try to create a new user, ie "newusername" with email "new@username.es" I get the validation error "You have to include an @ symbol in your email" but refering to username field.

I tried to use a format validation in the user model, but it doesn't solved anything

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :authentication_keys => [:login]

  attr_accessor :login 

  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates :username, length: { in: 4..20 }
  validates_format_of :username, :with => /\A[-a-z]+\Z/

   #####   and also 

  validates :username,
   :presence => true,
   :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false },
   :format => { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/ },
   :length => { in: 4..20 }
```

I couldn't find in Google anyone else that had the same issue.

I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: I realized that the error message is only javascript, without sending the form. I'am using bootstrap, and I wonder if this validation could be part of bootstrap.

Comment: OK it is solved. The error was that I copied the username filed in the view from the email field and I forgot to change email_field to text_field `<%= f.email_field :username , autofocus: true %>`